# Check is style attribute does not exists using javascript selector method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to only select `ARTICLE` items that do not have the style attribute set.

I could do this easily with jQuery but I'm using a library that is javascript only, called [scrollreveal](https://scrollrevealjs.org/).

I can easy get items that have the style attribute using this `ARTICLE[style]`.

But I want to reverse this and get items that do not have a style attribute, in the same way using a not equal to `!=` operator on the selector.

I've tried this...

```
// scroll reveal article
window.sr = new ScrollReveal({ reset: false });
sr.reveal('ARTICLE[!=style]', {
   duration: 1000
});
```

But it's not working as expected, does anyone know if its possible to achieve this using not equal too on a attribute selector?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there. The [:not pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) should do the trick:

```
article:not([style])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `:not([style])`:

```js
const matches = document.querySelectorAll('div:not([style])')
console.log(matches)
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="width:100px;"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="baz"></div>
```

That is if I'm correct in assuming that `sr.reveal` uses `document.querySelector` internally.

Comment: I need to get `bar` and `baz`, not `foo`. `div[style]` returns `foo`

Comment: @joshmoto Oops. Edited.